# ASUS N56VZ not charging on 13.10

Tags: 13.10, asus, battery

I'm new to running Ubuntu (or Linux for that matter) as a desktop OS, I do however have experience on the server side of Linux.

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my ASUS N56VZ-S4215H. It was no where near a smooth operation, I had to do several reinstalls to get it to work. I was faced by several issues and some I was able to resolve (booting into GRUB commandline instead of Ubuntu and, installing the NVIDIA GPU driver (that's a real pain in the ass!)).

I'm still however faced by several issues:

It seems my laptop is no longer charging. The indicator on the top right has been on 40% for hours now. Did I break my laptop or is the indicator false?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1:
The charging problem has been resolved. My BIOS was running v215. But after upgrading to v217 charging worked again! :D I'm still looking into the function keys, but that seems to be a known problem with users of Linux on the ASUS N56VZ laptops. If I find a solution I'll update it here.

EDIT 2:
Removed 2nd problem and created new topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/378532/some-function-keys-not-working

Comment: How about you ask about one problem at time?

Comment: Is that really the preferred way to ask things here? Creating several "topics"? That's usually what gets people angry.

Comment: first of all its a non stable ,experimental OS . So these kind of issues are obvious . and yes this is not a correct way of asking many things in one single thread..

Comment: @Sushantp606 13.10 is stable already....

Comment: are u sure , bcos one week before i was trying to install spring tool suit and it wasnt installed properly plus cant use the tabs in eclipse too..??

Comment: The Ubuntu website doesn't mention anything about 13.10 being non-stable release. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
Should I delete this topic and create two separate topics?

Comment: @DjormhiWijgman you can also edit this one so it asks 1 question and create 1 new one. Comments will be removed when we inform a mod or if all users above do that themself. 1 other thing: we also like that if you find a solution to create an answer and upvote + accept it. That way we all know it got solved and the systems engine does not keep putting this on the frontpage ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind I just removed the 2nd problem. I've also solved it already, but as a new user I can't submit my own answer until 8 hours after posting.

Answer (score 1):

The battery not charging is now solved. My BIOS had the 215 version, after updating it to v217 it is working again.